# In arm assembly language, will " sub r3, r2, 5 " modify the value stored in r2?

Tags: assembly, arm, low-level

Will the instruction just put the result in r3 leaving r2 unchanged or does it change r2 also?

Comment: `sub r3, r2, 5` is literally: `r3 = r2 - 5`..

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFFEJF.html

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow. Why did this question receive downvotes? How should I ask questions here?

Comment: @Barath: Your question is Ok IMHO, but some people may have considered you did not make enough research on your own with widely available information sources, such as [this one](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289908389.htm), in order to answer your question by yourself , but this is just a guess. Please note that you can debug an arm assembly program using,say, [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/)(https://www.qemu.org/) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), on a PC, even on Windows, in order to experiment. Feel free to ask in the case  you would need more details.

Comment: A general guide how to ask questions is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Barath: an [on-line assembler/simulator](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm) may help you, along with Arm documentation of course, to answer a lot of your own questions while learning.

Answer (score 1):

Only the destination register is modified.